# Best practice for background processing mobile push notification broadcasts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, concurrency, backgroundworker, sidekiq

I have a rails app on Heroku where I want to let users send broadcast push notification to their followers.

I am trying to use Sidekiq as background job processing worker. I can think of something like this:

```
current_user.followers.each do |follower|
  PushWorker.perform_async(follower.id)
end
```

Now let's say this user has 1 million followers. How do I deal with this? I think queuing itself will take a lot of time and the web request will be left hanging until the queuing has finished.

I thought about passing current_user.followers object as parameter but that's not idempotent. Perhaps this is a newbie question, I would appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: Its definitelly better to send it in batches (it has offcours limits, which depends on service - GCM/APNS, please read their documentation, not sure but GCM allows to 500 or 1000 ids in one batch request and APNS is *not limited*, they close connection if their limit exceed ). For this purposes you can use http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html AR Batch API and perform async *perform_async([id,id,id])*.